# divide XAdES-T generation into two jobs

Tags: xades4j

I want to ask if there is  a way in xades4j to divide XAdES-T generation  into two jobs.

job1: In Internal network , generate the signature without timestamp.

job2: Connect to TSA and add timestamp to the signature generated before.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/xades4j/wiki/SignatureEnrichment).

You can generate a XAdES-BES and later start a verification process that extends the form to XAdES-T using the the overload on [XadesVerifier](http://xades4j.googlecode.com/svn/release/1.3.0/javadoc/reference/xades4j/verification/XadesVerifier.html) that takes a [format extender](http://xades4j.googlecode.com/svn/release/1.3.0/javadoc/reference/xades4j/production/XadesSignatureFormatExtender.html) as an argument.

Or you can also use the format extender directly.